# Does endocrine noradrenaline stimulate sympathetically innervated cells?

Tags: autonomic-nervous-system

Cells that are innervated by the sympathetic nervous system, does endocrine noradrenaline target the same receptors on them? Are they dually activated by both nervous and endocrine noradrenaline?

Comment: Welcome. Is this a homework question?

Comment: Nope. Norepinephrine happens to be both endocrine and neuronal, technically the endocrine circulation should reach same receptor sites as the neuronal. Was interesting. Asked.